# Are empty Binary Search Trees valid?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I have two questions regarding binary search trees, both about empty trees.

1. Is an empty tree (null) valid?
2. Is a root node without children valid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, and yes.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what an empty tree is of course depends on your implementation, as does the meaning of the word "valid", but in general I would say "yes" to both questions. The empty tree represents the case where the set of entities you are intersted in is empty, and the single node the case where the set contains one entity.

Answer (score 2):

A single node with no children is certainly valid and according to [Binary Tree Structure](http://cnx.org/content/m17289/latest/):

> A (mutable) binary tree, BiTree, can
>   be in an empty state or a non-empty
>   state:
>
> - When it is empty, it contains no data.
> - When it is not empty, it contains a data object called the root element, and 2 distinct BiTree objects called the left subtree and the right subtree.

For completeness, this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) is a pretty useful summary of terminology and the like.

Answer (score 1):

> Is an empty tree (null) valid?

There is no tree if it is empty. Hence the question of validity doesn't arise.

> Is a root node without children valid?

Yes.  That is a tee with only one element in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing together apples and oranges:

1. `null` is a value in some programming languages, and it is related upon the concrete representation of your implementation of the data structure
2. "Empty" is a property of the abstract data structure that we call "binary search tree"

Now, a tree is an ordered set: nothing more, nothing less. A set can be empty, of course! This means that, in your **implementation**, something similar to:

```
MyTree tree = null
```

represent an empty tree? Well, it depends upon your model.
You can think, for ex.,  that an empty subtree should be represented by a node without value and with the references to the leafs nullified: in that model, a `null` pointer is meaningless from a logical perspective. But this is only **one** approach! The sentinel-based approach is a joy to program with, but it's memory expansive: you can then model empty nodes with just null. In that case, a `null` pointer can be an empty tree.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree can be defined recursively as:

```
A single node with either no children, or with two children - 
each of which is a binary tree.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes both conditions are true.
For a binary tree, each node can have zero, one, or two children.
If a tree has only a root node and no other node then it is called a NULL tree.