# What does an empty binary search tree look like?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write code for a binary search tree that has some basic functions. I am just having trouble with what an empty tree would look like. I know that with a linked list that there is a head that points to a nullptr. But since a binary search tree's root is an actual node, what value will be held in the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your tree implementation, but usually if the root itself is an empty node (e.g. `nullptr`) then it's an empty tree. If your root doesn't have a value even if the tree is non-empty, then look for the left and right child instead. But as said, you should know that already since it's your implementation, I guess. And if not, the type surely has an `is_empty()` method.

Comment: So the root of my binary search tree would have the rightChild, leftChild, and data variables all pointing to nullptr if it was empty?

Comment: That could well be the case, yes.

Answer (score 0):

An empty tree is the exact same as no tree at all. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810881/are-empty-binary-search-trees-valid)

Programmatically spoken, the pointer itself that would generally hold the address of the trees root element is null.